# multiple definition of global with gmock-global in unit testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I am trying to mock global function using https://github.com/apriorit/gmock-global library.

Note: this description contains example of the real scenario not the exact real scenario. Also I am not allowed to make any changes to global.hpp.

My example dir structure looks like below

```
--src
------global.hpp
------classA.hpp
------classB.hpp
------main.cpp
--ut
------classATests.cpp
------classBTests.cpp
------main.cpp
```

The ut/main.cpp tests testcases in classATests.cpp and classBTests.cpp.

global.hpp contains a global function

```
int giveIndex()
{
    return 1;
}
```

classA.hpp calls giveIndex() global function

```
#include "global.hpp"
class A
{
public:
int checkIndex() { return giveIndex(); };
}
```

classB.hpp calls giveIndex() global function

```
#include "global.hpp"
class B
{
public:
int checkIndex() { return giveIndex(); };
}
```

classATests.cpp contains

```
#include <memory>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gmock-global/gmock-global.h>
#include "src/classA.hpp"
MOCK_GLOBAL_FUNC0(giveIndex, int(void));

using namespace ::testing
struct classATests : public ::testing::Test
{
    void Setup() override
    {
        sut_ = std::make_shared<A>();
    }
    std::shared_ptr<A> sut_;
};
TEST_F(classATests , checkIndex)
{
    EXPECT_GLOBAL_CALL(giveIndex, giveIndex()).WillOnce(Return(1));
    sut_->checkIndex();
}
```

classBTests.cpp contains

```
#include <memory>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gmock-global/gmock-global.h>
#include "src/classB.hpp"
MOCK_GLOBAL_FUNC0(giveIndex, int(void));

using namespace ::testing
struct classBTests : public ::testing::Test
{
    void Setup() override
    {
        sut_ = std::make_shared<B>();
    }
    std::shared_ptr<B> sut_;
};
TEST_F(classBTests , checkIndex)
{
    EXPECT_GLOBAL_CALL(giveIndex, giveIndex()).WillOnce(Return(1));
    sut_->checkIndex();
}
```

The issue now is when i compile and run UT for both classATests.cpp and classBTests.cpp i get errors saying

> ... multiple definition of 'giveIndex' ;
> and
> ... multiple definitions of gmock_globalmock_giveIndex_instance

Is there any way to avoid this issue ? classA tests and classB tests need to be in 2 different files like it is now.

Comment: Globals. No. Just don't.

Answer (score 2):

Functions defined in header files should be defined inline

```
inline int giveIndex()
{
    return 1;
}
```

otherwise you will get multiple definition errors if you include the header file more than once.

The alternative would be to only *declare* the function in your header file

```
int giveIndex();
```

and then define it (but not inline) in one of your cpp files.

This is the normal way to organise C++ code. gmock has nothing to do with this.

Comment: +1 for declaration in header and definition in the source file. Apart from that, there would be the solution to use include guards. But you usually want to avoid function definitions in header.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue while I had a function declared in a header and defined in a .cpp file.

It was caused by the inclusion of the .cpp file in the targets of my test cmake file. Once I removed it there, everything compiled correctly and the function was correctly mocked.

**Basic example of the issue:**

```
add_executable(
    test_executable
    test.cpp
    file_with_function_to_mock.cpp
    ...
)
```

**fixed:**

```
add_executable(
    test_executable
    test.cpp
    ...
)
```

I'm guessing if you're attempting to test a function within a cpp file and also mocking another global function in the same file, you would run into this issue as well. In that case, you'll have to rework the source code to be more testable. Whether it's moving the function to be mocked to another file, or wrapping the functions into a class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has 1 translation unit, and your tests have 3. `global.hpp` cannot be included in multiple translation units, so if you can't modify it, your test structure will have to change, such that `ut/main.cpp` is the only translation unit for your test executable that includes `global.hpp`.

```
--src
------global.hpp
------classA.hpp
------classB.hpp
------main.cpp
--ut
------classATests.hpp
------classBTests.hpp
------main.cpp
```

ut/main.cpp:

```
#include "classATests.hpp"
#include "classBTests.hpp"

// existing stuff
```

A much more preferable case would be to argue that `global.hpp` is fundamentally broken, and you need to fix it, as [john's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74503360/2610810) answer details.